# Reading UTF8 (24-bit) and outputting

Tags: c++, utf-8, visual-studio-2017, windows-10, g++

I have a UTF8 text file containing 8-bit and 24-bit UTF8 encodings (ASCII and Japanese).

My goal is to read in characters, one by one, then output something like this:

```
{'V', 0x02},
```

This is a C++ language initialization entry, where the first parameter is the UTF8 encoding and the second parameter is the index or position within the file.

My first step is to successfully read the UTF8 text file and output to the console.

Here's a sample of the input file:

```
 ()+-0123456789Vanoty˄˅いおがきくさしすせただてでなにのびまみむめりるれをん
```

Here's a sample of the output from my program:

```
$ ./main.exe
Size of wchar_t: 2
32
40
41
43
45
48
49
50
51
52
53
54
55
56
57
86
97
110
111
116
121
4294953604
4294953605
4293034116
4293034122
4293034124
4293034125
4293034127
4293034133
4293034135
4293034137
4293034139
4293034143
4293034144
```

Here's my code:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Size of wchar_t: " << sizeof(wchar_t) << "\n";
    std::ifstream japanese_file("japanese_font_glyphs_all_112_qty_horizontal_layout.txt", std::ios::binary);

    char c = '\0';
    char32_t    utf8_char = 0;
    while (japanese_file.read(&c, 1))
    {
        unsigned int bytes_in_encoding = 1u;
        if ((c & 0x80u) == 0U)
        {
            bytes_in_encoding = 1u;
        }
        else
        {
            if ((c & 0xF0u) == 0xE0u)
            {
                bytes_in_encoding = 3u;
            }
            else
            {
                if ((c & 0xE0u) == 0xC0u)
                {
                    bytes_in_encoding = 2u;
                }
            }
        }
        char32_t    utf8_encoding = 0u;
        switch (bytes_in_encoding)
        {
            case 1:
                utf8_char = c;
                break;
            case 2:
            {
                char c2 = 0;
                japanese_file.read(&c2, 1);
                utf8_char = (c * 0x100ul) + c2;
            }
                break;
            case 3:
            {
                char c2 = 0;
                japanese_file.read(&c2, 1);
                char c3 = 0;
                japanese_file.read(&c3, 1);
                utf8_char = (c * 0x10000ul) + (c2 * 0x100ul) + c3;
            }
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        std::cout << utf8_char << "\n";
    }
    
    japanese_file.close();

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The output shows that the size of `wchar_t` is 2, which is not large enough to hold the 24bit encoding of the Japanese glyphs.

So, what code do I use to output the 24-bit UTF8 encodings (as a single glyph) to the console?

**Settings**:
g++ (GCC) 10.2.0 -- Cygwin
Windows 10
Visual Studio 2017

The application I'm writing will be running as a console application on Windows 10.

**Edit 1 -- Background**
My application will generate C++ data statements used for creating indices to a display chip's register of bitmaps.

Here's the struct definition and some example entries:

```
struct UTF8_To_Bitmap_Index_t
{
    char32_t    encoded_character;      //!< UTF8 encoding.
    uint8_t     bitmap_index;           //!< Index of glyph within the font.
    uint8_t     padding_alignment;      //!< For alignment purposes, not used.
};
static const
UTF8_To_Bitmap_Index_t default_conversion_table[] =
{
    {'¡', 0x01, 0u}, 
    {'À', 0x02, 0u}, 
    {'Á', 0x03, 0u}, 
    {'Ã', 0x04, 0u}, 
    {'Ä', 0x05, 0u}, 
    {'Å', 0x06, 0u}, 
};
```

Comment: Er, two bytes (wchar_t on Windows) is more than big enough for all but really, truly obscure Japanese characters. Your UTF-8 parsing is wrong. Why not use a library? Windows has ICU installed, you can easily handle all of this using the ICU libraries.

Comment: The correct name is "[UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8)". And you can encounter up to 4 bytes per character, not only 24 bits.

Comment: @AmigoJack Bytes per _encoded_ character doesn't matter (I always accept CESU-8, but if you want to be strict, then UTF-8 is a maximum of 4 octets). Bytes per _decoded_ “character” varies, but if you mean per _code point_ then it is _three_ == 24 bits. However, you only need the third octet for code points outside the BMP. (All normal Japanese code points are _inside_ the BMP.) So if OP sticks to the BMP then it doesn’t matter. But if it does, since Windows uses UTF-16, _prefer to use a library for decoding and encoding._ ICU is built-in on all Win OS, and handles this beautifully — use it.

Comment: @Dúthomhas: The BMP has ~60000 characters. A two-octet UTF8 encoding has the form `110xxxxx 1yyyyyyy` so by the pigeonhole principle we can prove that the vast majority of BMP characters require 3 octets of UTF-8. Hiragana and Katakana could well be two octets, but the Kanji alone are too numerous to fit into two UTF-8 octets.

Comment: Oh, it seems I misunderstood OP’s desire to be to _decode_ UTF-8 data. I am unsure how he intends to do a font glyph lookup with the encoded values, but, hey, the very first example of output shows a Unicode code point, as does the very last. Perhaps OP can clarify...?

Comment: You don't want `{'V', 0x02},` you want `{L'V', 0x02},` to create a wide-character constant, or `{u32'V', 0x02},` to create a 32-bit character constant, etc

Comment: I suggest avoiding the character constants and just using the integer value.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT → The following assumes you wish to *decode* the UTF-8 to a Unicode code point value, useful for lookup tables and finding glyphs in fonts.

(Disclaimer: I do not have cygwin installed; what follows uses MinGW-w64 and assumes a bash-compatible command-line. You may have to make adjustments for cygwin’s weirdnesses.)

To find and use Windows’ ICU you need to take a few steps. Open a shell prompt (bash/zsh/whatever cygwin gives you) and type:

```
cd /mnt/c/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/Windows\ Kits/
```

→ Remember, you can always hit `TAB` to help you out.

### Find the ICU headers.

```
find ~+ -name 'icu*.h'
```

You’ll get a list of files in at least one directory. Choose the directory with the largest version number. For me it is “10.0.17763.0”. This is the path that you will add to CPATH (Be sure to use proper character capitalization and escape those spaces and parentheses):

```
(Makefile) CPATH += /mnt/c/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/Windows\ Kits/10/Include/10.0.17763.0/um
(Terminal) export CPATH=/mnt/c/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/Windows\ Kits/10/Include/10.0.17763.0/um/
```

See the example below for how to deal with what header(s) to actually include in your source code.

### Find the ICU lib files

```
find ~+ -name 'icu*.lib'
```

Choose the same version number as above and select correct architecture. For most modern PCs it’s “x64”. This is where GCC gets obnoxious: you can’t just add this to your LIBRARY_PATH. Instead, you must specify the full path in your program’s sources at the command-line.

```
/mnt/c/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/Windows\ Kits/10/Lib/10.0.17763.0/um/x64/icuin.Lib
/mnt/c/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/Windows\ Kits/10/Lib/10.0.17763.0/um/x64/icuuc.lib
```

Cheating, you could just copy them to the working directory (which is what I will assume you do with the example below ;-)

### Compile

```
g++ -Wall -Wextra -pedantic-errors -O3 -std=c++17 -o example example.cpp icuin.Lib icuuc.lib
strip example.exe
```

The corresponding command-line for MSVC is:

```
cl /EHsc /W4 /Ox /std:c++17 example.cpp
```

### Example Program

Be aware that printing UTF-8 to the console in the old **Windows Console** using purely C or C++ facilities is a bit tricky and inconsistent. The new **Windows Terminal** makes everything work the way it ought. The code below assumes the new Windows Terminal — it will not display correctly on the old Windows Console without help.

(If you must display properly on the older Windows Console, I find that wprintf() tends to work most often, but I don’t bother since making it behave across compilers is impossible. I just use `WriteConsoleW` in a modified rdbuf attached to the output streams IFF they are attached to a console. That way the C++ code can be written using `std::cout` in the usual way.)

The “example.txt” file is the same text you provided in your question, but any UTF-8-encoded file will do.

The `BUFFER_SIZE` value on line 47 is intentionally small to highlight how ICU’s `ucnv_toUnicode` function works (doing exactly what you are asking for). I would personally use a larger buffer, anywhere from 100 to 1024 elements, depending on how much stack space you wish to eat.

An alternative would be to use `std::vector` for the input and output buffers — you could even provide a default argument buffer size to select that. Just pay attention to your requirements and don’t over-engineer.

As noted above, *which* ICU file(s) get included depends on weird Windows versioning madness. If you do not have “icu.h” available on your system then you must use the older “icucommon.h” and “icui18n.h” files. Do so by adding `-DSUPPRESS_LEGACY_ICU_HEADER_WARNINGS` to your command-line.

The following code uses a function to construct a `std::map`. Notice how the file offset *must* be the key value, or you’ll have collisions. You could, of course, just print the result and forget returning a map. This is just an example of how to solve the problem using ICU.

```
#include <ciso646>
#include <filesystem>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <memory>
#include <string>

using namespace std::string_literals;


#ifdef SUPPRESS_LEGACY_ICU_HEADER_WARNINGS
  #include <icucommon.h>
  #include <icui18n.h>
#else
  #include <icu.h>
#endif

#ifdef _MSC_VER
  #pragma comment(lib, "icuuc")
  #pragma comment(lib, "icuin")
#endif


// Function to convert bytes from file --> map of {file offset, Unicode code point}

std::map <size_t, char32_t>
map_utf8_file_offsets( const std::filesystem::path & filename )
{
  std::map <size_t, char32_t> result;

  // This is how we get {offset,uchar} pairs -- using a UTF-8 UConverter

  UErrorCode err;
  std::shared_ptr <UConverter> ucnv8
  (
    ucnv_open( "UTF-8", &(err=U_ZERO_ERROR) ),
    []( UConverter * ucnv8 ) { if(ucnv8) ucnv_close( ucnv8 ); }
  );
  if (!ucnv8.get()) throw u_errorName( err ) + " (Could not create UTF-8 converter)"s;

  // We'll process the file in small chunks

  std::ifstream f( filename, std::ios::binary );
  if (!f) throw "Failure to open file: " + filename.string();

  constexpr int BUFFER_SIZE = 10;  // adjust to your liking
  char          octets    [BUFFER_SIZE];
  UChar         codepoints[BUFFER_SIZE];
  int32_t       offsets   [BUFFER_SIZE];
  UChar       * p_codepoint;
  const char  * p_octet;
  size_t        offset_base = 0;

  // For each chunk
  while (f.read( octets, BUFFER_SIZE ) or f.gcount())
  {
    // Convert it
    ucnv_toUnicode
    (
      ucnv8.get(),
      &(p_codepoint=codepoints), codepoints+BUFFER_SIZE,
      &(p_octet    =octets),     octets    +f.gcount(),  // true: gcount ≤ BUFFER_SIZE
      offsets,
      f.gcount()!=BUFFER_SIZE,
      &(err=U_ZERO_ERROR)
    );
    if (err) throw u_errorName( err ) + " (UTF-8 conversion error)"s;

    // Store results
    auto n_codepoints = p_codepoint - codepoints;
    for (int n = 0;  n < n_codepoints;  n++)
    {
      result[ offset_base+offsets[n] ] = codepoints[n];
    }
    offset_base += BUFFER_SIZE;
  }
  ucnv_resetToUnicode( ucnv8.get() );

  return result;
}


// Helper to print Unicode characters to the console since cout/wcout can't do it directly

std::string to_utf8( char32_t c )
{
  UErrorCode err = U_ZERO_ERROR;
  char s[5];
  int32_t n = 0;
  UChar uc = (UChar)c;
  return u_strToUTF8( s, 5, &n, &uc, 1, &err );
}


int main()
try
{
  for (const auto & [offset, c] : map_utf8_file_offsets( "example.txt" ))
  {
    std::cout << "{'" << to_utf8( c ) << "', " << offset << "},\n";
  }
}
catch (const std::string& s)
{
  std::cerr << s << "\n";
  return 1;
}
```

Well, that’s it.

Comment: The plan is to write to the console so the data can be copied and pasted into another project's source file.  I have a "conversion" table that is 127 items and I really don't want to do it by hand (because of the possible typo's).

Comment: I can easily switch over to Visual Studio 2017 if that will make development easier.

Comment: Choice of compiler won’t matter. For a back-end utility like you want you don’t really even need a compiler — a Python or Tcl interpreter will be so much easier. The example code I made above would be ten or so lines in a Tcl script. So, the struct you provided above is absolute: `char32_t encoded_character` is the UTF-8-encoded byte string (and _not_ the decoded Unicode code point value)? If it is the UTF-8 string, is it stored big endian or little endian, or endianness to match the machine? (I presume an x64 processer, which is little endian?) continued...

Comment: ...continued: Would it make more sense to output the integer value instead of a character literal? Do you not want the third member value listed in the output, even if it is just `, 0 },`?